# Return Parent and Child from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    Id       INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    Name     VARCHAR(255)
    SomeProp VARCHAR(255)
)
CREATE TABLE Child (
    Id       INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ParentId INT NOT NULL
    ChildA   VARCHAR(255)
    ChildZ   VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I wish to write a stored procedure that accepts `@name` as a parameter, finds the Parent matching that name (if any), returns that Parent as a result set, and then returns any children of that Parent as a separate result set.

How can I efficiently select the children?  My current naive approach is

```
SELECT @id = FROM Parent WHERE Name = @name
SELECT * FROM Parent  WHERE Name = @name

SELECT * FROM Child WHERE ParentId=@id
```

Can I avoid selecting from Parent twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naïve approach looks OK, except that you don't have a UNIQUE constraint on `Parent.Name`, which means you could have duplicate parent names, but would only return children matching the first Id you find.  Also there is a syntax error on your first SELECT, which should be:

```
SELECT @id = Id FROM Parent WHERE Name = @name
```

An alternative would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Parent 
WHERE Name = @Name
ORDER BY Name

SELECT Child.*
FROM Child C INNER JOIN PARENT P ON C.ParentId = P.Id
WHERE P.Name = @Name
ORDER BY P.Name
```

which would return all parents whose name is @Name and all their matching children.

Comment: The real table does have a UNIQUE constraint, but thanks for pointing that out.  The INNER JOIN seems a better approach to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join like this and never select the id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Child c
JOIN Parent p on c.ParentId = P.Id
WHERE p.Name = @name
```

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with Joe's answer.

Another solution is that you can save results of finding Parent in a separate variables.

```
SELECT @id = Id, @someprop = SomeProp FROM Parent WHERE Name = @name

IF @id IS NOT NULL -- means that we found something
    SELECT @id, @name, @someprop

SELECT * FROM Child WHERE ParentId = @id
```